# How to create elastic-beanstalk env using CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation

I have a .Net app which I want to deploy to Elastic-Beanstalk using CloudFormation template. I tried it via a Sample Template but didn't work. Can I get a sample Template which help me to achieve this. I am using below template- But it is getting failed while creating Environment.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Resources:
  sampleApplication:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application
    Properties:
      Description: AWS Elastic Beanstalk Sample Application
  sampleApplicationVersion:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ApplicationVersion
    Properties:
      ApplicationName:
        Ref: sampleApplication
      Description: AWS ElasticBeanstalk Sample Application Version
      SourceBundle:
        S3Bucket: <myBucket>
        S3Key: <my.NetBuild>.zip
  sampleConfigurationTemplate:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ConfigurationTemplate
    Properties:
      ApplicationName:
        Ref: sampleApplication
      Description: AWS ElasticBeanstalk Sample Configuration Template
      OptionSettings:
      - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:asg
        OptionName: MinSize
        Value: '1'
      - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:asg
        OptionName: MaxSize
        Value: '2'
      - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment
        OptionName: EnvironmentType
        Value: LoadBalanced
      SolutionStackName: 64bit Windows Server Core 2012 R2 running IIS 8.5
  Environment:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment
    Properties:
      ApplicationName:
        Ref: sampleApplication
      Description: AWS ElasticBeanstalk Sample Environment
      SolutionStackName:
          Ref: SolutionStackName
      TemplateName:
        Ref: sampleConfigurationTemplate
      VersionLabel:
        Ref: sampleApplicationVersion
```

Comment: 1) Where did you find this template? 2) What error do you get?

Comment: I found this on aws docs itself. I am not sure what's the exact error. I am creating a stack using Cloud formation and it is getting Failed while Creating Environment. It just says "Environment is terminated by user" .

Comment: can you share the link where you found it?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-elasticbeanstalk.html